Unable to receive customer initiated messages in webhook - Whatsapp Cloud API Webhook
Unable to receive customer initiated messages in webhook - WhatsApp Cloud API Webhook. I had subscribed to all events and when trying test from developers console of meta, webhook is called with POST. But it does not call the webhook when a user sends a new message.
Seems like not an issue with webhook as it got registered, but not getting hit after that.

It was my mistake, but posting the answer for anyone else's future reference.
Follow as mentioned in here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/subscribed_apps/ to subscribe the with the WABA.
I got the issue resolved by doing the same.
